# A div inside an inline element: bad or not?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a JavaScript tooltip program and wonder if it's alright to add the tooltip box (that is, a div node) as a child of the target that may be a span node or some other inline element, so the dom is as follows:

out of this:

```
<span onmouseover="tooltip(this).display('A \"Hello World\" program is a computer program which prints out \"Hello World\" on a display device.');">Hello World!</span>
```

turns into this when the tooltip has added the tip box:

```
<span onmouseover="tooltip(this).display('A \"Hello World\" program is a computer program which prints out \"Hello World\" on a display device.');">Hello World!<div id="tooltip">A "Hello World" program is a computer program which prints out "Hello World" on a display device.</div></span>
```

If the tip box is positioned relative to its parent it's easier to handle the mouseout event and others. So would it bad to insert a div inside an inline element in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not conform to the standard, but this should be the easier way and it work cross browser.